# Check Checkboxes according to the data from the database

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I have a form in my website that I want to update the information of the user (Edit Profile) and some of the informations of the user has to do with the diseases that might a user has. 
I have checkboxes in order to select any disease but how I can have already checked checkboxes according to the data from my database table. 
The code for the checkboxes is the below...

```
<label id="Disease">Your Disease(s):</label><br />
    <!--emfanizei tis epiloges gia ta diseases me basi auta p exoume sti basi mas -->
    <?php
  $sql = "SELECT name FROM disease";
  $query_resource = mysql_query($sql);
  while( $name = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_resource) ):
?>
    <span><?php echo $name['name']; ?></span>
    <input type="checkbox" name="disease[]" value="<?php echo $name['name']; ?>" /><br />

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

My database table is named as patient and look likes this 
[image]

And my checkboxes look like this...
[image]

My update code ...

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])){

            $fname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["fname"]);
            $lname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["lname"]);            
            $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["email"]);
            $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST["password"]);
            $age = ($_POST["age"]);
            $disease = implode(",",$_POST["disease"]);         

            $query="UPDATE patient
                    SET fname = '$fname', lname = '$lname', email = '$email', password = '$password', age='$age', disease='$disease'
                    WHERE username='$username'";

            mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());
            if(mysql_affected_rows()>=0){
                echo "<p>($username) Record Updated<p>";
            }else{
                echo "<p>($username) Not Updated<p>";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Sidenote question: Your other question http://stackoverflow.com/q/29717770/ earlier, you're using PDO, but in this you're using `mysql_` functions; why? You're not mixing those different MySQL APIs now, are you?

Comment: @Fred-ii- because this is what the asked

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i am using mysql in this page because i started long time ago and i dont have the time to change it

Comment: (1) your `patient` table is poorly designed. Comma separated lists - `Allergy,Heart Disease,Neurological` - should be done as relational tables as in this format it is more difficult to do what you want. (2) Specifically to your question. You need to query your `patient` table to get their diseases, but you don't show that attempt here.

Comment: What you need to do is implode or explode on the comma and using `IN()`. As stated by @Sean about your comma-seperated list.

Comment: @Fred-ii- edited my question in order to check the update query because i have implode there

Comment: You need to use checked="checked" attribute if you want to display the state of your checkbox as mentioned in the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

`<input type="checkbox" name="disease[]" value="<?php echo $name['name']; ?>"<?php if (in_array($name['name'], split($disease, ','))) echo ' checked'; ?> />`

For XHTML you may want to write: `echo 'checked="checked"';`

Comment: `(in_array` from which table did you get that. I mean where are you selecting the table?

Comment: in_array is a standard php function, type php + what you want and you will find stack overflow or other useful articles. http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Comment: also i cant understand what is in the `...` can you write please the whole code???

Comment: `...` is the same as before. You can basically insert this php command anywhere you like in your input, but you have to be careful to add spaces or to be save return `" checked "` instead.

Comment: you mean something like that `<input type="checkbox" name="disease[]" value="<?php echo $name['name']; ?>" <?php if (in_array($name["name"], $name["diseases"].split(","))) echo "checked"; ?> />`

Comment: yes, this seems to be correct, but the comments about the data design are true, comma seperated lists in a database are almost always bad. It can slow down requests incredibly.

Comment: Yes, split was wrong JS style instead of PHP... split + PHP in search engine and you would have seen. PHP luckily gives helpful errors unlike others that give no error messages at all.

Comment: I saw that you edited your code but still i am getting errors (http://prntscr.com/6v8tpr)

Comment: I think this wasn't the newest version of it.

Comment: I am getting this error with this code `<input type="checkbox" name="disease[]" value="<?php echo $name['name']; ?>"<?php if (in_array($name["name"], split($name["diseases"], ","))) echo "checked"; ?>  />`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75588/discussion-between-maraca-and-dogface).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a checkbox to be checked per default you need to add the attribute:

```
checked="checked"
```

Go through the list of disease and if he has it in the database, then add the attribute to your input.

Answer (score 0):

With a simple "if" in the "while" statement you can check if the disease is in your list. If there is, you have to insert the keyword "checked" in your html code. 
The pseudocode should be

```
get all possible diseases
get all patient's diseases
while disease=over all diseases
   if(disease is in the patient's diseases list)
      echo "<input type="checkbox" ... checked >"
   else
      echo "<input type="checkbox" ... >"
```

That's it.